# open a file in perl run perl using html

Tags: perl

I have an HTML page in which I run a Perl script to get the value from HTML and writing it onto a file.
The problem I'm facing is that whenever I run the Perl script from the terminal as a root, the HTML page gets updated and runs fine, however if I try the same thing from HTML (using the Firefox browser) it fails. Perhaps because of a permission issue.

The following is an extract from my HTML page:

```
<div>  
    <form id="QA1_Insert" action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/person.pl" METHOD="POST" >    
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                             <td class="columnLabel"> Name</td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="Name"></td>
                            <td class="columnLabel">Address:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="Description"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
<input type="submit" value="submit"></form> 
      </div>
```

And here is my person.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use CGI ':standard';
use warnings;
use IPC::System::Simple qw(system capture);
use DBI;
use Cwd qw(chdir);
use FileHandle;
use Fcntl;


#sysopen (FILE ,"/root/info/person.txt",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0755);
open (my $file,"<","/root/info/person.txt");

chmod 755,$file;
print FILE "<html><head></head><body><p>sakshi</p></body></html>";

close (FILE);

print 
header(),
start_html(
    -title   => 'Command',
  -text    => '#520063'
);
print "Hello ";
print  end_html();
```

I have tried creating it with sysopen, which doesn't work due to permission errors. I've also tried chmod. However, neither are working. Any suggestions on how to solve it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your web server does not run as the *root* user. That is correct. It should not do that. Since your file is in root's home directory, the web server user cannot access it. The `chmod` command will fail as well as the `open`.

Put your output file in a directory that the web server can access (and should access, unlike root's stuff) and it will work.

---

Note that you have a mix of lexical and global filehandles there. Decide which one you want. (You want `$fh`!) Also you are opening the file for reading with `<` and then you try printing to it. That will also not work.

You should check the return value of the `open` call. For example, you can say:

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die $!;
```

Check your web server's log file to see the errors. You are using `strict` and `warnings`, which is good, but you do not profit from the error messages if you do not look at them. It's probably saying *500 Internal Server Error*. Your web server log has more information.

As [an alternative](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Carp), `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` will redirect them to the browser. Do not use this in production though.

Finally, note that CGI has been removed from the Perl core recently and that in recent releases of the CGI module on CPAN the HTML creation functions have been deprecated. They should not be used in new code.

Comment: You should also encourage the OP to check the status of every `open`, `chmod`, and possibly `close`

Comment: @simbabque: as u suggested i tried to run the perl script in user mode. and added die $!... now its showing permission denied. how to solve this? i tried changing the mode of user by chmod 755 /home/user1

Comment: @geek is the _permission denied_ because you cannot run the script, or because the `open` inside the script fails?

Comment: @simbabque: it is becuase of open... when i run it without open it works fine

Comment: @geek so the problem is you are trying to write into `/root/`. **Don't do that.** Your web server is not intended to go there. End of story. :)

Comment: worked :) :) i was so dumb.. i was trying it widout adding the user path :p sorry.. and thanku :)

Comment: @simbabque: it works with the terminal on the user profile.. but not from firefox browser. i have copied the html file to the user account and changed permission. creating the file in /home/user1/ on the browser i am getting permission denied.

Comment: is there anything regarding firefox settings??

Comment: @geek This has nothing to do with firefox in particular. The browser just displays whatever the webserver sends. If there are permission problems then it's in your program or between your program and the webserver. Unless you are seeing a 403 FORBIDDEN status code. Please create a new question explaining the current situation and someone might be able to help.